# Why I get an invalid redirect uri error in Keycloak when try to log on the aws console with SSO?

Tags: amazon-web-services, single-sign-on, keycloak, saml

I'm configuring Keycloak to use SSO for the login on AWS Console.
I have a private ec2 where I have my keycloak docker container running, also I have created a record dns associate to the ec2 private ip.
In front of my ec2 I have an ALB with target group for HTTPS on port 443 and the redirect works well.
I can login in admin console easily but when I try to create the client by following this https://neuw.medium.com/aws-connect-saml-based-identity-provider-using-keycloak-9b3e6d0111e6 guide I have an invalid redirect uri error.

I have tried to configure in this way [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TiavW.png)
and I can go the aws console but not in the way that I'm expect this.

When I try to recreate the steps illustrated in the guide with Home URL setted to /realms/myrealms/protocol/saml/clients and the same valid redirect URI I have an invalid redirect uri

Any idea about this problem? I have tried everything but nothing seems to work.

Thanks for the help and I hope it was clear my problems

Comment: I recently blogged about setting Keycloak up, integrating it with SSO so this might help as I found a lot of the blog posts didn’t really work for me https://dev.to/aws/integrating-keycloak-as-my-identity-provider-for-iam-identity-centre-part-one-deploying-keycloak-on-aws-2ol1

Comment: Hi, I already checked your post that was very helpful for other stuffs. I can update you that by setting Assertion Consumer Service POST Binding URL I can go to the aws console but I can't :"Response (with optional signature) must contain an assertion with a mandatory signature (Service: AWSOpenIdDiscoveryService; Status Code: 400; Error Code: AuthSamlInvalidSamlResponseException; Request ID: 8775ce82-f9b8-4e34-89e7-b08ab4029d87; Proxy: null) (Service: AWSSecurityTokenV20111201; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidIdentityToken; Request ID: 1ffcab45-6aa9-4c08-ab56-ebfa4da09973; Proxy: null)"

Comment: Any idea? Because I don't know how to go on

Comment: The only thing I can think might be the issue is that incorrect metadata has been uploaded, or maybe has become corrupted. I didn’t get this exact error but I’ve had similar ones due to that problem.

Comment: Hi Ricardo, I have resolved by setting SIGN ASSERTIONS on true in keys settings and set Saml assertions with url. But I have another question:  I have an attribute like this<saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">name@domain</saml:AttributeValue>that other team use to login, how I can set this type of attribute keycloak side? In this way they can get the attribute from the SAML Response, thanks